# Use of "oneself" in a sentence

Tags: grammar

I have written this sentence, does it make sense?

> In spite of all that drama, thoughts from which oneself will benefit
>   can always arise, and in this case it happened.

Comment: "In spite of all the drama, thoughts of how oneself may benefit can always arise, and in this case it happened."

Comment: It's probably better if the reflexive pronoun refers to the subject. *One* will suffice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a convoluted sentence. Its grammatical correctness and meaning are difficult for me to gauge. It seems you're looking for more than just grammar help, but for a comment on its understandability.

The use of the reflexive "oneself" doesn't seem right. "Thoughts of how one might benefit from something" would be correct. So would "thoughts of how I can help myself might arise" is an example of a reflexive reference that makes sense.

This sort of sentence can't really be understood in isolation; it refers to previous events, situations, or ideas. There are antecedents that we can't know: "all the drama" and "this case."

Finally, there is an assertion, which seems to be the point of the sentence: One's thoughts can benefit oneself. Put another way: "I might think of something, and in doing so, benefit myself." 
Is that a concept that many people will agree with? Is there such a truth that can be put more simply? For example: "if I look at something differently, I can gain insight." If that's what the idea is, I would use more specific words to express it: "A random thought can lead to an important insight." Or, "One never knows when a profound idea will arise from mundane circumstances."

If this is the internal monologue of a character in a drama, there might be a good reason for this sort of wording. However, if this sentence is trying to communicate a concept or idea to a general audience, you should try to use simple, direct, specific words and phrasing. Untangling the clauses would help.